# Check if verified list of emails at Paypal

Tags: email, verification, paypal

I apologize in advance if I am in wrong topic redirect me please if so.

I have a problem, I got about 500 emails from my company and they set me a task to see which emails are verified from paypal and which are not.

So I am asking is there a way or a software that imports the list and export the result of verification?

I have tried searching on google and on many forums but all I found is only for one email.

Comment: what email client or service are you using? Are the emails in a form of a list? or did they send you 500 separate emails to individually check?

Comment: they are all hotmails , they are in .txt file seperated by new line

Comment: Is there more information that you can share about the type / nature of emails - any similarity feature across all emails should help us set up rules to validate automatically

Answer (score 0):

If emails claiming to be from paypal do not have a [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail)-header, you can safely classify them as [SPAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spam).

You could [manually check](http://community.websense.com/blogs/securitylabs/archive/2011/09/12/email-spam-using-dkim-verification-for-analysis.aspx) the DKIM signature if one is present, but that's tedious for so many emails.

As a general solution, the email server should only accept the emails from paypal domains, if the DKIM signature of the eMail is valid.